# how to understand the return references in c++ functions?

Tags: c++

```
string& message(){
    static string str = "good good";
    return str
}
```

In the above code, the returned type of the function should be a reference to a string variable based on its signature. Well, on the other hand, inside of the function definition, a variable of type string is returned. Based on my understanding, object and the reference of object are sort of inter-changable? Or did I miss something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have e.g.

```
std::string foo = "foo";
std::string& bar = foo;
```

you basically do the same thing: You use the object `foo` to create the reference `bar`. After the initialization of `bar`, that variable is a reference to `foo`.

The same thing happens in your function: When you do `return str;` the compiler will create a reference to `str` and return that reference.

Comment: are all functions in c++ return by value or return by references?

Comment: @kkxx Depends. You can return a reference as in your example or return by value (without the &), thereby copying the value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Technically, returning "by pointer" is just returning by value, the value being returned might be a pointer but it's still by value. :)

Comment: I would like to make a small correction. The example you showed above, with `foo` and `bar`, slightly defers w.r.t their scope. whereas the `str` wouldn't be accessible as `str` after returning. the only way of accessing this `str` is by using that reference.

Answer (score 1):

They're not interchangeable.

When you pass something by value, you're passing a copy of the entire thing, the recipient can delete it or mutate it or do whatever and the original is left alone.

When you pass a reference, under the hood you're really passing a pointer (address) to the original. If the recipient messes with it, the original is affected. If the original is destroyed and you try to use the reference, you'll get problems.

You can also pass something by pointer explicitly: `string* bar = &foo;`.

and by rvalue reference: `string bar = std::move(foo);`, which tells the recipient you want to move the data without copying, leaving foo empty.

Answer (score 1):

@kkxx

My answer would probably be in a very layman language in the way I understand C++ references.

A reference is basically **another name** to the variable it is referencing to. It is essentially *renaming* the variable while the existing name is also accessible (inside the scope). This is the reason why references cannot be left uninitialized as you cannot *rename* something non existing.

*(I am still confused about whether or not we can view the memory address of a reference but that is a topic for another thread(or maybe already existing thread))*

So what you are doing is simply returning the reference to the `str` variable. it is like you are returning the `str` variable but the recipient of the function will be just another name to `str`.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think we can view the memory address of a reference of an object, which is the memory address of the original object. Maybe use &, which is the memory address operator, right?

Comment: I meant whether it takes up extra space in memory (like pointers do) and if yes then is it accessible? Actually, I have read somewhere that it does, but it is inaccessible. That is the confusion... but that is a separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is classified as `lvalue reference` in the scope of `message()` function. when you return by reference, you return the lvalue reference you already own, str. But when you return an lvalue by value, the copy constructor of that type is invoked, and a new string is constructed (as the instance of the string is static, rvo cannot be performed)

Hence, it boils down to this;

- use return by reference when you want to use that specific instance of a
  type
- use return by value when you want a copy of that instance of a
  type

Bear in mind that when you return by reference, you have to guarantee the lifetime of referenced instance outlives the caller site. In your example, you have provided that guarantee by making that variable `static`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo{
    foo(){
        std::cout << "foo is being default constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    foo(foo & f){
        std::cout << "foo is being copy constructed" << std::endl;
    }

};

foo doFoo(){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    static foo f;
    return f;
}

foo & doFooRef(){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    static foo f;
    return f;
}

int main(){
    auto f1 = doFoo();
    auto f2 = doFoo();
    // to preserve value type of doFooRef completely. plain auto basically perform std::decay_t over 
    // doFooRef's return type
    decltype(auto) f3 = doFooRef();
    decltype(auto) f4 = doFooRef();
}
```

The output of the code above is as follows (with no optimizations);

```
    foo doFoo()
    foo is being default constructed
    foo is being copy constructed
    foo doFoo()
    foo is being copy constructed
    foo& doFooRef()
    foo is being default constructed
    foo& doFooRef()
```

Let's break it out;

```
    foo doFoo()                      // the first invocation of doFoo
    foo is being default constructed // first invocation triggers static variable initialization inside of doFoo, so default constructor is called
    foo is being copy constructed    // doFoo returning by value, copy constructor is called
    foo doFoo()                      // the second invocation of doFoo
                                     // note that default construction does not appear again as static variable was initialized in first invocation already
    foo is being copy constructed    // doFoo returning by value, copy constructor is called
    foo& doFooRef() // first invocation of doFooRef
    foo is being default constructed // first invocation triggers static variable initialization inside of doFooRef, so default constructor is called
                                     // no copy constructor invocation, because we are returning the reference directly
    foo& doFooRef()                  // second invocation of doFooRef, no default construction, no copy construction as expected.
```